# Silverlight binding errors in the output window

Tags: silverlight, binding, elementname

I know that if there's an issue with the Path attribute in my binding expression, I'll get a binding error message in my output window, but is there anyway to debug a ElementName attribute issue?

I have tried things that I'm pretty sure don't exist like

ElementName=ElephantButt

and get nothing in the output window.

Thanks.

Comment: If your just trying to debug something, you might be able to write a converter that would check it and write to the output window.

Answer (score 0):

Put breakpoint to binding in XAML